# Clipping Geometry with a Plane in Three.js

Tags: three.js, buffer-geometry

I'm hoping to do simple collision detection with a Geometry/BufferGeometry against some planes and I was wondering if Three.js contains a way to return only the part of a BufferGeometry that's on one side of a Plane, as another BufferGeometry?

I know that you can use Three.js to clip meshes with Planes when rendering, however I can't spot a way to do the clipping outside of the GPU.

I know CSG.js could be used, but this seems overly heavyweight for what I need.

Comment: You're looking for Boolean mesh operations. Try [CGS.js](https://evanw.github.io/csg.js/). (_I am in no way affiliated with the CGS.js project_)

Comment: If you want a THREEJS adapted version of madebyevans CSG.js here is my port of it: https://github.com/manthrax/THREE-CSGMesh

and a demo:

http://www.vectorslave.com/csg/CSGShinyDemo.html

Comment: Thanks - so it seems there's nothing except CSG.js? Your THREE.js port looks great though. My issue is I want to do this pretty much every frame on an Oculus Quest, so I really want something speedy. I believe CSG.js does a bunch of extra housekeeping stuff that I don't need because it deals with non-regular shapes - basically all I want is a way of figuring out if a mesh sits even partially within a regular volume defined by a few planes.

Comment: If your geometry has not so many vertices you can check if any vertice is inside the volume defined by planes. If signed distance from the vertex to all the planes is negative, then it's inside the volume. https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Plane.distanceToPoint